# how to build individual war files when a project has multiple pom xml files?

Tags: java, maven

I want to deploy this  https://github.com/OhadR/oAuth2-sample 
as how to author says.

How do I get the 3 war files?

Which maven goal should I run from command line?

Comment: Did you import this project in your workspace from github?

Comment: `mvn deploy` should work.

Answer (score 0):

oAuth2-sample is the parent module.

The role of this module is to build the other modules defined within pom.xml

So if you see there are 3 modules defined in it(though 2 are commented out),

```
<modules>
    <!--module>auth-common</module>
    <module>common-crypto</module-->
    <module>authentication-flows</module>
</modules>
```

So if you run the maven, it will build all the modules as either by jar,war as defined in their individual pom.xml file.

Maven command that you can use,

> maven clean - To clear the class files of the projects
>
> maven compile - To compile the source code of the projects
>
> maven install - To install the project in m2 repository for use as dependency for other modules.

Comment: how do I build the war files for authentication server, a resource server, and a client app? the remaining 3

Comment: I think I will have to build them individually inside

Comment: Yes. Because those modules are not included in the parent pom.xml.
You can add those modules with in parent pom.xml and build your parent module which is oAuth2-sample in your case.